# HTML5 Canvas Line not showing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently following this tutorial to draw just a basic line (http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-canvas-tutorial-introduction/). I have tried with codepen(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOEYaa)

html

```
     <canvas id="exampleCanvas" width="500" height="300">
   <!-- OPTION 1: leave a message here if browser doesn't support canvas -->
          Your browser doesn’t currently support HTML5 Canvas. Please check caniuse.com/#feat=canvas for information on browser support for canvas. 

        <!-- OPTION 2: put fallback content (text, image, Flash, etc.) if the browser doesn't support canvas -->
    </canvas>
```

js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('exampleCanvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(50,50);
context.lineTo(250,150);
context.stroke();
```

css

```
canvas {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

and the black line does manage to appear. When I am using my browser, I added in the html tags but the lines are not showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('exampleCanvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(50,50);
        context.lineTo(250,150);
        context.stroke();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <canvas id="exampleCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
   <!-- OPTION 1: leave a message here if browser doesn't support canvas -->
          Your browser doesn’t currently support HTML5 Canvas. Please check caniuse.com/#feat=canvas for information on browser support for canvas. 

        <!-- OPTION 2: put fallback content (text, image, Flash, etc.) if the browser doesn't support canvas -->
        </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because code is being processed up to down.

Time at which JavaScript is trying to get context of canvas element, canvas doesn't exist.

Put Script code end of the body or call draw line on an event after body load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
     <canvas id="exampleCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
          Your browser doesn’t currently support HTML5 Canvas. Please check caniuse.com/#feat=canvas for information on browser support for canvas.
        </canvas>


     <script type="text/javascript">
         var canvas = document.getElementById('exampleCanvas');
         context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         context.beginPath();
         context.moveTo(50,50);
         context.lineTo(250,150);
         context.stroke();
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wondering, what if I place all the JS codes externally at another .js file. Does it still act the same as js file will be specified at the <head>? Why?

Comment: Yup. You should be calling canvas to draw only after body load. Or else put script tag at bottom.